# Choosing a specific item on click, but not all of the items with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, click

I am trying to have the action done to ONLY the item clicked, but the current result is to do the action to all items on the page. Thus, I would like to only select the specific "product_image" that I click on, not every "product_image".

```
$('.product_image').on('click', function() {
    $('.description').toggleClass('show-description');
  });
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML that contains `.product_image` and `.description` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to operating only on the clicked on item or something in the same branch of HTML as the clicked on item, it to use `$(this)` in the click handler as the basis for your selector.

1. If you want to target the element that was clicked on itself, then you use `$(this)` to get a jQuery object for that element.
2. If what you want to target is a child of the item that was clicked on, you can use `$(this).find("selector")` to find the relevant child.
3. If what you want to target is in the same branch, but not a direct child, then you use `$(this).closet("common parent selector")` to go up to the common parent and then `.find()` from there to find the item you're looking to target.

Assuming the `.description` element you want is inside the `product_image` item, then you can do this:

```
$('.product_image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.description').toggleClass('show-description');
});
```

or, sometimes they have a common parent and you do something like this:

```
$('.product_image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("common parent selector").find('.description').toggleClass('show-description');
});
```

If you add the relevant HTML to your question, we can advise much more specifically.

Comment: The `$('.product_image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.description').toggleClass('show-description');
});` worked perfectly